# Read hostname from a secondary filesystem

Tags: ubuntu, mount, hostname, fstab, initramfs

I'm trying to customize a preinstalled Ubuntu image for VM instances. My idea was to add a secondary filesystem to `/etc/fstab` (let's call it `/config`) and then symlink all relevant config files to that filesystem.

This approach works fine for `/etc/network/interfaces` but fails for `/etc/hostname`. Apparently the hostname is set before `/etc/fstab` is mounted, causing the symlink to fail.

How can I have `/config` mounted before the hostname is set? Or is there an alternative solution to this problem that does not require an early mount?

Comment: Just out of curiosity ... what do you want to gain by adding the secondary filesystem?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider The root filesystem is ext4 (obviously) while the secondary fs is fat32. The point is that there are plenty of libraries and tools to easily edit a fat32 image (without mounting it) which is much harder for ext4.